# Compare schema files in different repos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have 4 different git repositories, one local and three deployed on Heroku.

I'm looking for a fast way to check differencies in the `schema.rb` file, in case a migration or db reset has been forgotten in any of the apps.

I assume that basing on the solution given in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21101644/3205492) I would be able to fast check this difference? `git diff ref1:path/to/file1 ref2:path/to/file2`

I have named the remote repositories, i.e. remote_1, remote_2 etc.

I'm unsure though how to apply remote-names + path to get it right on Heroku, any advice on how the correct git command would look like with the above setup?

Comment: is the file path not the same? If so you may well do `git diff ref1 ref2 -- path/to/schema.rb`

Comment: there is even an example in that answer! `git diff remotename/branchname:remote/path/file1.txt local/path/file1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Compare remote repo with local:

```
git diff remote_1/master:db/schema.rb db/schema.rb
```

Compare remote repo with another remote:

```
git diff remote_1/master:db/schema.rb remote_2/master:db/schema.rb
```