# GIT: Notify on git section change

Tags: git

There is a code snippet which is doing a numerical test, if this test changes, i would like to notify some other departments, as they are using the same test.

Is there a way of sending notifications when a specific section of a code has changed?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your problem, but generally I would say that the test and what it tests should be part of the same repository, so that whenever someone changes the test and the tested code simultaneously, test and tested code stay synchronized throughout the revision history. If test and tested code are not part of the same repository, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[git: diff between file in local repo and origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101572/git-diff-between-file-in-local-repo-and-origin)

Cron a job to do the operations in the above link, examine the output, and send mail if the output is any different than empty string. The file has changed if the output is not empty.

You can create your own branch to diff it against either locally or in the upstream repo or you can just keep a copy of the file on the server that's running this cron job and compare the file to the master tip.